# Does showon work with form fields that are checkboxes?

Tags: joomla-4.x, form-fields-types, showon

I have a List form field type in my form, that selects (by showon) the values visible at a second (multiple) List form field type. That works fine.

Something like that:

```
<field name="animal" type="list" label="label">
    <option value="cats">cats</option>
    <option value="dogs">dogs</option>
</field>

<field name="breed" type="list" label="breed" multiple="true">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option showon="animal:cats" value="c1">c1</option>
    <option showon="animal:cats" value="c2">c2</option>
    <option showon="animal:dogs" value="d1">d1</option>
    <option showon="animal:dogs" value="d2">d2</option>
</field>
```

Now, I want to change the Second (multiple) List form field to be checkboxes, because it seems more intuitive to use.
Something like that:

```
<field name="animal" type="list" label="label">
    <option value="cats">cats</option>
    <option value="dogs">dogs</option>
</field>

<field name="breed" type="checkboxes" label="breed">
    <option showon="animal:cats" value="c1">c1</option>
    <option showon="animal:cats" value="c2">c2</option>
    <option showon="animal:dogs" value="d1">d1</option>
    <option showon="animal:dogs" value="d2">d2</option>
</field>
```

But it seems **showon** doesn't work with option's checkboxes type. Does it? or Am I missing something?